# How do I run simple xquery? Can I run XQuery in a browser itself?

Tags: xquery

I am an XQuery beginner. Do I need any software to run XQuery? Where do I type XQuery code - in HTML pages or XML? What extension should I use to save my XQuery files?

Answer (score 3):

You need an XQuery processor, this might run your XQuery code either locally, in the browser or on the Server. I would suggest buying Priscilla Walmsley's XQuery book and looking at the processors [Saxon](http://www.saxonica.com), [eXist-db](http://www.exist-db.org), [BaseX](http://www.basex.org) and [XQiB](http://www.xqib.org/). Saxonica also provides a Saxon-CE processor which runs in the browser.

XQuery files typically have the extension `.xq` or `.xqy`, although others are also in use.

Comment: I'd like to add BaseX as possible XQuery processor. In return, I would like to recommend this excellent new XQuery/eXist book: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920026525.do

Comment: Before you invest in Walmsley's book, note that the second edition is due May 2015, http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920035589.do. Also, if you want to try out your XQuery without installing anything new, head to http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/eXide/ or http://try.zorba.io/.

Comment: Saxon supports both XSLT and XQuery, but the in-browser version Saxon-CE supports XSLT only.

Answer (score 1):

This link can give you a quick idea about Xquery. http://www.stylusstudio.com/xquery_primer.html]. Also if ur looking at a solution to check xquery code on the fly, check this link out. https://icl.googleusercontent.com/?lite_url=http://emdin.info/r/xpath_checker/&ei=SIZmU8zx&lc=en-IN